# How to create a csv file with image id's and corresponding labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dataframe

I want to create a csv file which will contain column(Image_id , label) .The image id's are train1.png,train2.png, train3.png....train3099.png. Now, I want to store the image ids and corresponding labels . I have already written a base code , But I can't iterate the loops . I am beginner in python language, so there may have many errors. Thanks

```
import csv
cnt =0
with open('JoinImagesTrain.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Image_id", "Label"])
    if cnt<=150:
         writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "হতে"])

    elif cnt<=295:
    writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "সূর্যমুখী "]) 
      elif cnt<=447:
     writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "হাজার"]) 
      elif cnt<=619:
       writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "কাক"])  
       elif cnt<=772:
         writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "নাম"])
         elif cnt<=939:
          writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "দেশ"])
          elif cnt<=1092:
            writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "লোক"])
               elif cnt<=1262:
            writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "করা"])
                elif cnt<=1419:
                  writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "ঠান্ডা"])
                  elif cnt<=1572:
                    writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "সরকার"])
                    elif cnt<=1722:
                        writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "নেতা"])
                       elif cnt<=1870:
                         writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "সদস্য"])

                             elif cnt<=2042:
                              writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "মেয়ে"])
                               elif cnt<=2190:
                                  writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "ছেলে"])
                                     elif cnt<=2338:
                                       writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "জেলে"])
                                          
                                          elif cnt<=2505:
                                            writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "খেলা"])
                                             elif cnt<=2652:
                                                writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "বাংলাদেশ"])

                                                   elif cnt<=2799:

                                                         writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "শতাংশ"])
                                                            elif cnt<=2952:
                                                              writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "আলোচনা"])
                                                                 else:
                                                                   writer.writerow(["train" + str(cnt)", "গবেষণা"])
   


                                                                                 cnt +=1
```

can anyone help?
thanks in advance

Comment: If the last count value is fixed i.e. `count=3099` then you can simply use [while loop](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-while-loops/) and increment the count value in each iteration. Make sure your `if-elif-else` conditions are well indented.

Comment: You can also prepare a result with lists of lists having image IDs and label and at the end write that list of lists to CSV file.